# Why is there a greater-than symbol on sites without a custom design?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: why is this here]

[image: it happens on meta too]

[image: it's here too]

I'm relatively certain that's not supposed to be there.

Comment: This is actually our graduation design. Worth the wait!

Comment: @Fatalize Our? No, it doesn't appear only on PPCG.

Comment: Presumably that represents a CLI caret? As in "type your command here".

Comment: +1 for freehand circles.

Comment: @Fatalize I wish I could give bounty to comments, lol.

Comment: Looks like it's saying "There's nothing greater than PPCG"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whoops. An extra `>` slipped into the markup.

Fix pushed and being deployed.

Comment: I just happened to be in that file already. Just by chance. Honestly.

Comment: So you're saying you're *definitely* not the one who accidentally put the `>` there? :P

Comment: I cannot confirm nor deny...

Comment: Looks cool. Like a terminal. `> Ethereum beta`

Comment: @Oded Well, I think you're guilty. :P

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος - my feelings. They are hurt.

Comment: @Oded So is everyone's web browser's. :-)

Comment: Not anymore, @MichaelKjörling... not anymore...

Comment: @Oded Indeed, it's fixed now for me.

Comment: It didn't look so bad :-)

Comment: It's spring in NY, the `>`'s are breeding. You might want to get a `&#x1f431;` around the office.